# Is there a way to manipulate pandas pivot table to obtain a specific format of output?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, pivot-table

i got this pivot table result

[image: result i got]

my pivot table code looks like this:

```
result = pd.pivot_table(excel, values=["Percent"], columns='Date', index='items', aggfunc={"Percent":np.mean})
```

but i need to looks like this:

[image: result i want]

Anyone knows how i can get it?

i tried:

```
result.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

but drops the wrong column

Comment: `excel.pivot_table("Percent", columns='Date', index='items')`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify `aggfunc` with a dict as you have only one column of value:

```
result = excel.pivot_table(index='items', columns='Date',
                           values='Percent', aggfunc='mean')
```